# Generating a countable mutually disjoint collection of arbitarally small measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

More specifically

> Assume that X has a collection of arbitarally small measurable sets. Is it possible to then generate a countable mutually disjoint collection of arbitarally small measurable sets.

It is obvious that you can make a countable collection. It isn't so obvious that you can make a disjoint collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the hypothesis is that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $A$ a measurable subset of $X$ such that $\epsilon > m(A) > 0$. You want to show that there exists a sequence of disjoint measurable subsets $A_n$ such that $m(A_n)>0$ and $m(A_n)\to 0$.

Consider a sequence of measurable subsets $B_n$ so that $0<m(B_{n+1})<\frac{1}{2}\cdot m(B_n)$ for all $n\ge 0$.  Now take 
$$A_n \colon = B_n \backslash (\cup_{m>n} B_{m})$$

It is easy to see that $m(A_n) > 0$ for all $n$ and $m(A_n)\to 0$. Moreover, the $A_n$'s are pairwise disjoint.